# can log into Minecraft at home (on Mac) but not recognised on on PC elsewhere..?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My son logs into Minecraft on our computer (Mac) but since he joined the Minecraft club at school he cannot log in there. We know the login details are correct but he gets the message that they are unrecognised or the referenced account cannot be logged on to.  Other people are using Minecraft there so its not a firewall issue. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Did he try to login with the account's email or just the username?

Comment: Have you tried to login on Mojang website? Also have in mind, that if you fail to login like few times, Mojang servers will ban your IP for some time (an hour, or at most 24 hours), so if you try it over and over again, it won't then work at all.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Minecraft login is really buggy. This stuff happens ALL THE TIME. Sometimes, it is because of what you're logging in with. If your son has had Minecraft for a short amount of time, then you need to log in with your username. If he's had it for a while, try logging in with the email. For more details about which to use, visit the [Mojang website](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/329527-minecraft-log-in?b_id=5408)

Other than that, maybe you tried with failed attempts too many times. Like your phone will lock you out, maybe Mojang does the same thing-ish? I don't really know at this point.

Just remember, Minecraft login does this. Just stay calm. And if all else fails, Mojang.com or Minecraft Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your son's minecraft account was created using the free version of minecraft. Sorry if I offended you and you did pay for minecraft.